# ViewModel data with dynamic rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, viewmodel

I have a view that list a collections of items. I allow the user to add and delete rows dynamically from the view. This all works fine. I am adding and deleting rows in the controller then sending the model back to the view,

```
return View("EditPage", Dmodel);
```

The problem is one of my fields uses a dropdown list,

```
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor( m=>m.Order[i].Software, Software())
```

After I remove a row from my collection and return to the view, the dropdown does not select the correct value for the row that took the place of the deleted row.

I noticed that these two model access methods are returning different values,

```
m=>m.Order[i].Software --This is wrong
Model.Order[i].Software -- This is correct
```

it looks like the lambda expression is looking at the old data, but Model is looking at what I passed to the view.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the *item* you're removing is an `Order` or a `Software`? Also, where does `i` comes from?

Comment: i is part of the loop in my view to loop over the order collection. Software is one of the fields of the order record.

Comment: Ok, but `Software` is also a collection, right? Yet, you're removing an item from `Order`, not from `Software`. Is that correct?

Comment: Software() returns the values for the dropdown list, this never changes.

Comment: I'm sorry John, but it's a little hard to understand the context your code is in. Could you provide more details, such as the model classes (Order  and Software) and methods (Software())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning view in POST method, use redirect, so instead of

```
return View("EditPage", Dmodel);
```

redirect

```
return RedirectToAction("EditPage",...);
```

This pattern is called POST-REDIRECT-GET. After successful operation you should redirect to GET.

Currently existing `ModelState` values conflict with new ones. You deleted values in model, but `ModelState` still holds them, so you have issues with indexing. You can fix it differently, but using this pattern is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks, this did help. I also noticed that ModelState.Clear() seemed to work too. I'm guessing that jumping to get is forcing the ModelState to clear.

Comment: @John: Yes. Redirecting clears `ModelState`, because it is new request.